# Saving and navigating through multi-panel xyplots which exceed 1 page

Tags: r, printing, save, lattice

I have a simple problem with a multi-page, multi-panel xyplot: My data describes growth rates of a population of 200+ animals. For visual inspection of the growth rate I would like to be able to quickly eyeball the fitted values of my growth models for each animals in the population. 
To do this I produced a lattice xyplot:

```
mygraph<-xyplot(growth~age|AnimalID, layout=c(2,2))
```

Because AnimalID has so many values the multi-panel plot is useless if I don't restrict the number of panels per page. The problem is that I cannot navigate through the pages with pageup and pagedown. The graphic window runs through the pages swiftly and stops at the last page. I tried to save the graph using this:

```
png("U:\\My Documents\\mygraph.png")
print(mygraph)
dev.off()
```

However this also only saved the last page of the multi-page plot. The plot should contain more than 50 pages.
Any idea how I can access and save the other pages of the plot?

Comment: you could use `pdf()`, which allows multipage output. Maybe `png("mygraph%03d.png")` works (in the sense that it automatically creates new files for each page), I haven't tried

Comment: Thanks. Both options work.